# How to avoid apply to range in copying conditional formatting in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I want to change the selected cell(A1) colour if its value is greater than other cell(B1) in same row.When i copy this conditional formatting to other multiple cells(A2,A3,A4...) in below rows, it is applying to range based on same cell value i.e (B1).I want it to be applied to A2 based on B2

Answer (score 1):

If you go back and edit your conditional formatting formula, just change `$B$1` to `$B1`.

When creating a conditional format, Excel uses absolute references by default. Removing the `$` from in front of the one makes the row reference relative.